# Python with kivy moving multiple 3D objects

Tags: python, 3d, kivy

I have a rather simple goal of drawing a few spheres in a 3D space and adjusting their location according to some function. I want to use python with kivy to accomplish this because it make touch screen interfacing super simple, and I found a [repository](https://github.com/nskrypnik/kivy-3dpicking/blob/master/main.py) which takes care of most of the heavy lifting with respects to programming.

From this code in the main.py function, I want to draw n spheres, and then update their locations later on (this is done under the draw_elements(self) function, and LOP[] is a list of the class 'points')

```
    def drawPoints():
        print self.scene.objects
        for i in range(len(self.LOP)):
            PushMatrix()
            point = self.LOP[i]
            point.shape = self.scene.objects['Sphere']
            point.color = _set_color(i/10., (i+1)/10., 0., id_color=(int(255/(1+i)), int(255/(1+i)), 255))
            point.shape.scale = Scale((i+1)/10.0,(i+1)/10.0,(i+1)/10.0)
            self.LOP[i] = point
            point.shape.scale.origin =  (point.loc[0],point.loc[1],point.loc[2])
            _draw_element(point.shape)
            PopMatrix()

    drawPoints()
```

When the points are drawn, they are at their stated origin.
Later on the program calls the update_scene function thanks the the clock scheduler.

```
 def update_scene(self, *largs):
    def randLoc(point):
        newLoc = (0.1*random.random(),0.1*random.random(),0.1*random.random())
        oldLoc = point.shape.scale.origin
        newLoc = ( newLoc[0]-0.05+oldLoc[0], newLoc[1]-0.05+oldLoc[1], newLoc[2]-0.05+oldLoc[2] )
        return newLoc
    def updateLocs(self):
        for i in range(len(self.LOP)):
            point = self.LOP[i]
            point.shape.scale.origin = randLoc(point)
    if not self.pause:
        updateLocs(self)

    pass
```

When this update function is run, only the sphere that was drawn last moves, though it does move correctly.

How can I move the other spheres I drew earlier?

(my source code can be found [here](https://github.com/CrakeNotSnowman/nSpect/blob/master/nSpect.py) though it's really just build off of the first repository)